# Strange behavior passing a String (java.lang.String) to WebView.loadUrl()

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to pass a string to a JS function (with no luck) like so:-

```
m_WebView.loadUrl("javascript:myFx('" + myStringArg + "')");
```

Inside the JS function, i have `console.log("received param = "+ theArg);`
If i pass the java string, i get `Uncaught SysteaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL --` from the Troll that is LogCat. 
HOWEVER, If i pass a literal e.g `m_WebView.loadUrl("javascript:myFx('QWERTY123')");`, it works fine.
What am i missing?

EDIT#2: FIXED! The downloaded string had a trailing newline character, which when passed to loadUrl messed up the javascript call...An invisible gotcha!

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace. What is the value of `myStringArg` ?